# SQL Server 2008 Search Single Column or Multiple Columns using several keywords

Tags: sql-server-2008, search, filtering, wildcard

Using SQL Server 2008 I am trying to run a stored procedure that accepts a parameter that is a list of keywords such as 'short black curly'

What I want to do is search a description column in my table using the 'short black curly' but it does now work.

I am doing this in my stored procedure -

```
WHERE (Description Like '%' + @Desc + '%' Or @Desc IS NULL)
```

If I send 'short' in my parameter it works, if I send 'shorty' it does not, if I send 'short black curly' it does not work. I really want it to be able to search the column using any of those combos. Is this possible?

Comment: Just to clarify:  If description contains any ONE of those key words, you would expect that record to be returned?  Say if descriptions were 'Black Sheep', 'Larry, Moe and Curly','Short Circuit' or 'Ba ba white sheep have you any wool' only the first three would be returned.

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Comment: I believe this is only going to be accomplished using [full text searches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571(v=sql.100).aspx) using keyword [contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787(v=sql.100).aspx); otherwise the paramaters would have to be split prior to passing and use "or" like logic. and even then, you would need to prepare the string `CONTAINS(Description, '"short" OR "black" OR "curly"')`

Comment: Thanks xQbert. So are you saying I would need to split the parameter or could I do this assuming @Desc = "short black curly"                                               SELECT ImageID FROM Images                                                                WHERE CONTAINS(Description, @Desc)

Comment: Close. Read though the dup question and the syntax  from MSFT links for contains.  You'll note the use of apostrophe and quote contains(description, @Desc) where `@desc = "word" OR "word2" or "word3"` also note FULL TEXT search has to be ENABLED! [they are by default in 2008](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403375(v=sql.105).aspx)